# Error when processing the authentication request in WSO2 Identity Server - NullPointerException

Tags: authentication, wso2, single-sign-on, saml, wso2-identity-server

I'm having a trouble when authenticating with the WSO2 Identity Server. 
I have a web page named avis.com, when I enter the page, click the login button, then the web page navigates to the login form of WSO2 Identity Server. But, when I enter use name and password into the form and click login. A error page appears as:

```
SAML 2.0 based Single Sign-On

Error when processing the authentication request!
Please try login again.
```

At the Apache Tomcat Log, errors appear:

```
Nov 07, 2013 3:12:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SAML2ConsumerServlet] in context with path [/travelocity.com] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.travelocity.saml.sso.SamlConsumerManager.getResult(SamlConsumerManager.java:272)
    at com.travelocity.saml.sso.SamlConsumerManager.processResponseMessage(SamlConsumerManager.java:246)
    at com.travelocity.saml.sso.SAML2ConsumerServlet.doPost(SAML2ConsumerServlet.java:73)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

At the com.avis.saml.sso.SamlConsumerManager.getResult(SamlConsumerManager.java:272):

```
private Map<String, String> getResult(XMLObject responseXmlObj) {

        if (responseXmlObj.getDOM().getNodeName().equals("saml2p:LogoutResponse")) //line 722{
            return null;
        }

        Response response = (Response) responseXmlObj;

        Assertion assertion = response.getAssertions().get(0);
        Map<String, String> resutls = new HashMap<String, String>(); // line 72

        /*
         * If the request has failed, the IDP shouldn't send an assertion.
         * SSO profile spec 4.1.4.2 <Response> Usage
         */
        if (assertion != null) {

            String subject = assertion.getSubject().getNameID().getValue();
            resutls.put("Subject", subject); // get the subject

            List<AttributeStatement> attributeStatementList = assertion.getAttributeStatements();

            if (attributeStatementList != null) {
                // we have received attributes of user
                Iterator<AttributeStatement> attribStatIter = attributeStatementList.iterator();
                while (attribStatIter.hasNext()) {
                    AttributeStatement statment = attribStatIter.next();
                    List<Attribute> attributesList = statment.getAttributes();
                    Iterator<Attribute> attributesIter = attributesList.iterator();
                    while (attributesIter.hasNext()) {
                        Attribute attrib = attributesIter.next();
                        Element value = attrib.getAttributeValues().get(0).getDOM();
                        String attribValue = value.getTextContent();
                        resutls.put(attrib.getName(), attribValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return resutls;
    }
```

At the com.avis.saml.sso.SAML2ConsumerServlet.doPost(SAML2ConsumerServlet.java:72)

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                                                                                   throws ServletException,
                                                                                   IOException {

        String responseMessage = request.getParameter("SAMLResponse");

        if (responseMessage != null) { /* response from the identity provider */

            Map<String, String> result = consumer.processResponseMessage(responseMessage);

            if (result != null && result.size() == 1) {
                /*
                 * No user attributes are returned, so just goto the default
                 * home page.
                 */
                response.sendRedirect("home.jsp?subject=" + result.get("Subject"));
            } else if (request != null && result.size() > 1) {
                /*
                 * We have received attributes, so lets show them in the
                 * attribute home page.
                 */
                String params = "home-attrib.jsp?";
                Object[] keys = result.keySet().toArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                    String key = (String) keys[i];
                    String value = (String) result.get(key);
                    if (i != result.size()) {
                        params = params + key + "=" + value + "&";
                    } else {
                        params = params + key + "=" + value;
                    }
                }
                response.sendRedirect(params);
            } else {
                // something wrong, re-login
                response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
            }

        } else { /* time to create the authentication request or logout request */

            try {
                String requestMessage = consumer.buildRequestMessage(request);

                response.sendRedirect(requestMessage);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

At the com.avis.saml.sso.SamlConsumerManager.processResponseMessage(SamlConsumerManager.java:246)

```
public Map<String, String> processResponseMessage(String responseMessage) {

        XMLObject responseXmlObj = null;

        try {
            responseXmlObj = unmarshall(responseMessage);

        } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnmarshallingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return getResult(responseXmlObj); // line 246
    }
```

Actually, I have two web pages, but here I mentioned one because they are the same. I'm doing a single sign on project that two service provider (web pages) are central authenticated at WSO2 Identity Server using SAML2.0 and OpenSAML

I don't know whether I miss some step when configure or not? Are there any important point I must keep in mind for my web page to authenticate successfully.

Comment: what is exactly on line `SamlConsumerManager.java:272` ?

Comment: here it is:
Map<String, String> resutls = new HashMap<String, String>();

Comment: no, I don't think so. It is likely that one : `if (responseXmlObj.getDOM().getNodeName().equals("saml2p:LogoutResponse")`

Comment: Sorry, It's my fault. That's what you said!!!

Comment: can you please post full exception log ? It seems that problem might be in `responseXmlObj` being null after processing response message

Comment: I think the problem is here but don't know how to fix. The error only appears after I entering user name and password then press Login button :(

Comment: I posted the full exception log above (Apache Tomcat log)
When the exception occurs, The Identity Server display a warning:
[2013-11-07 20:15:59,616]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.Au
thnRequestProcessor} -  Destination validation for Authentication Request failed
. Received: [null]. Expected: [https://localhost:9443/samlsso]

Comment: can you search for `WebService Response ` in the logs, or just post `full log` (including after `at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)`), there will probably some `Caused by...` statements ?

Comment: I'm running my project by Netbeans.
After at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) there is nothing.
Do you wanna see the full log of the Identity Server?

Comment: did you search for "WebService Response" in your logs ? Seems like you are missing certificates, possibly to validate the server

Comment: There is no results for "WebService Response" in the full log (I posted above).
How can I know whether I'm missing certificate or not? And how to fix this?

Comment: try to google for the warning you have in the log, read documentation to see what you need for setup, I guess I can not help much more.

Comment: I google it but not help :(
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same exception.Updating unmarshall method as below resolved my problem.

```
private XMLObject unmarshall(String responseMessage) throws ConfigurationException,
                                                        ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
                                                        IOException, UnmarshallingException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();


    byte[] base64DecodedResponse = responseMessage.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(base64DecodedResponse,0,responseMessage.length());
    System.out.println(new String(decoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    String s = new String(decoded,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    Document document = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(s)));

    Element element = document.getDocumentElement();
    UnmarshallerFactory unmarshallerFactory = Configuration.getUnmarshallerFactory();
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = unmarshallerFactory.getUnmarshaller(element);
    return unmarshaller.unmarshall(element);

}
```